# How do I close modals in a Slack App using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, slack, slack-api

I am attempting to close a modal, I've just started working on a Slack App in Google Apps Script and have tried numerous combinations to attempt to close it.

The documentation says I can respond with

```
{ "response_action":"clear" }
```

and I tried that many times with no success.

I've sent this alongside my slack token to the views.update endpoint with no luck. I get a response back that says a view_id is required. And then when I send it with the view_id the modal still does not close.

When I send the request to the view.update url I send it as following:

```
var options = {
      method :"post",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      headers:{Authorization: "Bearer " + SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN},
      status: 200,
      payload:{"view_id":id, "response_action":"clear"}
      }

var val = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endPoint,options)
```

The documentation also says I can send a HTTP 200 ok response. But I'm not sure how exactly to do that, and I haven't seen what that looks like when using Google Apps Script.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

In order to return an HTTP 200 OK response I just had to do the following:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput();
```

from the doPost() method.